# Stochastic processes with a dense set of jumps

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

For some continuous-time random processes on $\mathbb R^+$ or on $\mathbb R$, the set of points where there is a jump discontinuity is dense on the line and for no two intervals does the increment on one of them determine the increment on the other.

My questions are:

1. Which processes of that sort are commonly studied and where can one best read introductory expositions of them?
2. What applications do they have?

(The one example that comes most readily to my mind is the "Dirichlet process".)

Comment: What do you mean by "never perfectly correlated"?

Comment: I suppose $X(t) = \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q \leq t} (1+A_{n(q)})2^{-n(q)}$  is an example of such a process, with $\{A_1, A_2, A_3, ...\}$ iid Bernoulli random variables, and $n(q)$ is the index of rational number $q$ in some particular listing of the rationals $\mathbb{Q}=\{q_1, q_2, q_3, ...\}$.

Comment: @Michael : "Never" in this case means for _no_ pair of disjoint intervals.  "Perfectly correlated" means the correlation is $1$ or $-1$, which means almost surely one of the two increments is an affine function of the other.  Maybe I should have used a stronger condition: For no two disjoint intervals is the conditional distribution of the increment on one interval, given the increment on the other, a "delta" distribution.  The increment on one interval never determines that on another. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael : I've rephrased it. Maybe it will be clearer to some people now. $\qquad$

Comment: @ Michael Hardy : I would go for Infinite Activity Lévy processes which are mostly used in Quantitative Finance. For a presentation on Lévy processes maybe the book by Applebaum might cover the infinite activity case as well as the book of Sato and the book by Bertoin. Best regards